SwiftUI My Classes dont get injected properly
Im fairly new to SwiftUI and Im trying to build a small game to get used to the syntax but I have the problem that I created a class and created 3 instances in the @main struct but when I try to use them in my View they all turn into the first instance
Class:
import Foundation

class WorkSpace: ObservableObject {
    var title: String
    var income: Int
    
    init(title: String, income: Int) {
        self.title = title
        self.income = income
    }
}


@Main struct:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct LifeSimulationApp: App {
    @StateObject var doctor = WorkSpace(title: "Doctor", income: 60000)
    @StateObject var lawyer = WorkSpace(title: "Lawyer", income: 50000)
    @StateObject var carseller = WorkSpace(title: "Car Seller", income: 30000)
    @StateObject var player = MainPlayer()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(doctor)
                .environmentObject(lawyer)
                .environmentObject(carseller)
                .environmentObject(player)
        }
    }

}

View:
import SwiftUI

struct OccupationView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var doctor: WorkSpace
    @EnvironmentObject var lawyer: WorkSpace
    @EnvironmentObject var carseller: WorkSpace
    @EnvironmentObject var player: MainPlayer

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "text.book.closed.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()

                    Text(player.occupation)
                        .font(.title)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()
                }

                Section {
                    Toggle("\(doctor.title) (\(doctor.income)€)", isOn: $player.isDoctorOn)

                    Toggle("\(lawyer.title) (\(lawyer.income)€)", isOn: $player.isLawyerOn)

                    Toggle("\(carseller.title) (\(carseller.income)€)", isOn: $player.isCarsellerOn)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(player.name)
        }
    }
}

struct OccupationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        OccupationView()
            .environmentObject(MainPlayer())
            .environmentObject(WorkSpace(title: "Doctor", income: 60000))
            .environmentObject(WorkSpace(title: "Lawyer", income: 50000))
            .environmentObject(WorkSpace(title: "Car Seller", income: 30000))
    }
}


Preview:
enter image description here

You can only have 1 EnvironmentObject of each type.

And maybe you are better of creating them as properties in the view instead, as @State properties or let declared.

Note, when you use class WorkSpace: ObservableObject you should have
@Published var title: String and
@Published var income: Int, otherwise the properties are not managed properly by the View.

That is because you can only have one @EnvironmentObject of each type, since the compiler only checks the type. You can actually name your environment variable whatever you want, as long as the type is correct and it will recognize it. You have a few options, the easiest would be creating an ObservableObject that contains all the WorkSpace objects you need, probably as an array.
Depending on your use case, you could also extend environmentValues to contain doctor, lawyer and whatever else you need.
Or you could just pass the StateObjects in the inits.
